# mb_convert_encoding error return null in php 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6

i have a problem with mb_convert_encoding, when i get a json and use this function return null, but these only pass in one server what have php 5.6.40,
becouse i test in other server that have php 5.5.9 and this working good.

my code

```
   $res = file_get_contents('php://input');// get for url json 
    
    
    $res = utf8_encode($res);

    $res = mb_convert_encoding($res,'UTF-8','UTF-8'); 
    $response = json_decode($res);
```

please someone help me becouse i don't know if is a version or  other think.

Comment: PHP v5.9 doesn't exist. Do you mean PHP v5.5.9?

Comment: Also, to clarify: are you saying this works in 5.6 but not in 5.5.9?

Comment: yes, version 5.5.9

Comment: don't work in 5.6.40 but work 5.5.9

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code that's given, but I'm thinking it either has something to do with the change in how PHP uses `php://input`, or an extension issue related to `mb_convert_encoding`